# R shiny: formattable package based on another matrix of the same size

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, formattable

I'm trying to format an matrix based on another matrix of the same size. Take a look at this picture for example, I would like to highlight table A based on if the cell in Table B is less than 0 or not. I'm using `formattable` package in R shiny and in my code I used this line below but i'm not sure what to put in the ifelse statement.

```
renderFormattable({formattable(tableA,row.name=FALSE,align="l",list(

lmv = formatter("span",style = x ~ ifelse(x > ??)
style(color = "red", font.weight = "bold", background="orange"),NA))
```

Here is the picture:

[image: Example click here]

In addition, I'm also wondering how do I add a mouse hover over for those cells in red? Is there anyway to do that using formatable or datatable?

Comment: Color coding using `DT` http://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Comment: @Sumedh, the example will only work if the interval are the same for all cells but in my case it doesn't. Any idea how to reference each cell in a loop in DT?

Comment: All cells don't need to have the same criteria. The above example works if you have different criteria for different columns.

Comment: @Sumedh, yea but mine is not. For each row (each ID) it has a different criteria for each column.                                                          backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow')) In other words, the c(0,1) range is different for each cell.

Comment: Can someone please help take a look? I really couldn't figure this out and have been trying many things but none of them works.